# Найти максимум вхождений из массива в строке другово массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, поиск

Имеется два массива. 1й со словами, 2й с предложениями.

Требуется найти все совпадения в строчках массива $arr_str.
У меня находит только одно вхождение, ни как не соображу, как поставить next
для поиска следующего слова если первое найдено.

```
$arr_word = array('первый', 'второй', 'третий', 'четвертый', 'пятый', 'шестой');
$arr_str  = array('стр. содержит одно вхождение третий', 
                  'стр. имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй',
                  'тут 3 совпадения - шестой, второй и четвертый');

foreach ($arr_word as $val_word){
  $pattern_word = "#".$val_word."#";
foreach ($arr_str as $val_str){
    if(preg_match($pattern_word, $val_str)){ 
   // как прикрутить такое - если совпадение найдено ищи следующие в этой же строке.
        echo $val_str . " < - found - > " . $val_word . "<br />";
    }
  }
}
//выводит 
/* стр. имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй < - found - > первый
   стр. имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй < - found - > второй
   тут 3 совпадения - шестой, второй и четвертый < - found - > второй 
   и т.д. */

// мне нужно так : имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй < - found - > первый второй
// тут 3 совпадения - шестой, второй и четвертый < - found - > шестой второй четвертый
```

наверное, надо счетчик совпадений дописать и поставить проверку но я не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Цитата "как прикрутить такое - если совпадение найдено ищи следующие в этой же строке."
В таком случае, в первом цикле нужно перебирать не $arr_word, а $arr_str, если по другому, то вы будете искать в одной строке, несколько раз одно и тоже совпадение..

```
foreach( $arr_str as $val_str )
{
   foreach( $arr_word as $val_word )
   {
       $pattern_word = "#".$val_word."#";
       if(preg_match($pattern_word, $val_str))
       { 
           echo $val_str . " < - found - > " . $val_word . "<br />";
           continue;
       }else
      {
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

Код не проверял, просто как пример....

Comment: //выводит :стр. имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй < - found - > первый
стр. имеет 2 вхождения первый и второй < - found - > второй